# Formatting training data and labels for a small CNN built using Keras Sequential API

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am working on a simple Convolutional Neural Net (CNN) to perform classification. The goal of this net is to classify 224 x 256 scalar arrays into one of three different discrete states. Each value in these arrays represents an integer pixel value extracted from [the Nintaco emulator](https://nintaco.com/api.html).

I have a fairly simple model constructed as follows:

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models
import numpy as np

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(32, 16, strides=8, activation='relu', input_shape=(224, 256, 1)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
                  loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
                  metrics=['accuracy'])

data_points = [
    [33, 15, ... 25, 16]
    [33, 15, ... 25, 16]
    ...
    [33, 15, ... 25, 16]
    [33, 15, ... 25, 16]
]
labels = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3] for i in range(len(data_points))]
train_set, test_set, train_labels, test_labels = train_test_split(data_points, labels)

train_labels = np.expand_dims(train_labels, -1)
test_labels = np.expand_dims(test_labels, -1)

model.fit(
        training_set,
        training_labels,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=(testing_set, testing_labels)
    )
```

Attempting to fit this results in a failure with the follwoing error:
`InvalidArgumentError: logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [32,3] and labels shape [96] [[{{node loss/dense_1_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits}}]]`

It is fairly clear to me that I am structuring the label data improperly for this function, but I am uncertain as to how it should properly be formatted.

At present, I am solely focused on getting the fit function to work; I am wholly indifferent to the efficacy or construction of the network (though if anyone sees any flaws with my overarching approach, please do not hesitate to raise them).

How can I properly format my labels for my training data?

Comment: what's `training_labels.shape`, should be a 1d vector, read more [here](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-use-keras-sparse_categorical_crossentropy/)

Comment: I changed `labels = [[0.1, 0.2, 0.3] for i in range(len(data_points))]` to `[random.randint(0, 2) for i in range(len(data_points))]` and was able to get the limited case working. Thank you very much!

Comment: added as an answer, glad I could help, please [accept_the_answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this can be closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be with your loss function and the shape of your label
For [sparse_categorical_crossentropy](https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-use-keras-sparse_categorical_crossentropy/) the label should be a 1d vector.

check the `training_labels.shape`